# Use constant as class name

Tags: php, language-construct

I need to use constant as class name for acces to this class static property, that is

```
class a {

    public static $name = "Jon";

}

define("CLASSNAME", "a");

echo CLASSNAME::$name;
```

this returns error, that class `CLASSNAME` not exists.
There is some solution ?

Comment: Perhaps if you state what you actually want to do, there could be some better alternative ways. This may be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible with reflection:

```
class a {

    public static $name = "Jon";

}

define("CLASSNAME", "a");

$obj = new ReflectionClass(CLASSNAME);
echo $obj->getStaticPropertyValue("name");
```

If it is a good design choice is another question...

Comment: An update on this: From PHP 7, you can simply do: `echo (CLASSNAME)::$name;`

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into this problem because the class is based on a certain context that has to be given. So I made a function in my class that will return the class you require like so:

```
/**
 * Instantiate a class by class name in variable
 *
 * @param string $className The name of the class
 * @return mixed The instantiated class
 */
protected function getClass($className)
{
    return new $className;
}
```

Therefore you can call it by using `$class = new $this->getClass(static::CLASSNAME);` when you defined a constant within the current class that holds the name of the class you want to instantiate. In your case you can use it without the '`static::`' or with whatever variable you'd like to use. Do not forget to implement some error handling.

Answer (score -1):

Use PHP's absolute mess of dereferencing:

```
$CLASSNAME = 'a';
$a::$name;
```

Comment: I guess you meant $CLASSNAME::$name, cause this doesn't make sense, but even then, that's not what the OP asked for. You could do $class = CLASSNAME; $class::$name, though.