# How to get class from a constant array?

Tags: php, arrays, constants

I have about twenty different classes that are segregated in an assoc array similar to this:

```php
class a {public $val = 1;}
class b {public $val = 2;}
$classes = array("one"=>'a', "two"=>'b');
var_dump(new $classes["one"]()); // object(a)#1 (1) { ["val"]=> int(1) }
var_dump(new $classes["two"]()); // object(b)#1 (1) { ["val"]=> int(2) }
```

But now I want to do the array constant.

I can make it using `const VAL = array();` just fine.
The problem lies in making new objects using those classes

```php
class a {public $val=1;}
class b {public $val=2;}
const CLASSES = array("one"=>'a', "two"=>'b');
var_dump(new CLASSES["one"]());
```

fails with `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'` error.

I figured that I could reverse const array to variable again and it works fine:

```php
class a {public $var = 1;}
class b {public $var = 2;}
const CLASSES = array("one"=>'a', "two"=>'b');
$tempClasses = CLASSES;
var_dump(new $tempClasses["one"]()); // works
```

but why doesn't it work with a constant array?

I tried playing with parenthesis and `constant()` too. Neither `new (CLASSES)["one"]()`, `new (CLASSES["one"])()`, `new constant(CLASSES)["one"]()` nor `new constant(CLASSES["one"])()` work.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: `new (CLASSES["one"])()` works in PHP 8+. Demo: https://3v4l.org/BUJ8H. Otherwise, you can do `$one = CLASSES['one']; new $one();` in all versions. Demo: https://3v4l.org/89PP3

Comment: so it wasn't implemented before... that sucks.

Comment: I don’t know what you are exactly doing, but your code looks like it is going down an enum-like path which is [coming in 8.1](https://stitcher.io/blog/php-enums) and has existing support using many libraries, including [this](https://github.com/myclabs/php-enum)

Comment: If you aren’t going down enum path, this feels like a general factory pattern decide

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20278476/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/534159/2943403

Comment: I get user input word, then `strtolower` it and then do `CLASSES[$input]`. Because I don't want my classes to be all lowercase, and because I don't want to make a large switch statement (or regex if hell) with all possible inputs pointing to correct classes I just made an assoc array with "input"=>"ClassName" pairs. I of course check with `isset(CLASSES[$input])` if the input has a class corresponding to it.

Comment: At first I did it with `$classes` array but then I thought "Could I do it const?" and I failed to do it without making additional variable to "convert" constant array to a variable one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you would, but yes you can:

```
<?php

class a {public $val=1;}
class b {public $val=2;}
const CLASSES = array("one"=>'a', "two"=>'b');


$obj = (new ReflectionClass(CLASSES["one"]))->newInstance();

var_dump($obj);
```

Comment: That looks way worse than php8.0 additional parenthesis solution, but it works for php<8.0 so thanks! I just changed to php8.0